# HTML5's New <header> Element

Tags: html, header, element

I understand its functionality. Am I right to believe we now sandwich all h1 to h6 tags in between it?  Am I missing something?

Please be gentle, I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: I am almost ready to say yes.... Can you clarify what does `sandwich` means?

Comment: http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/

Comment: Depending on what you want, you could also use the `hgroup` tag. Using the `header` is a good practice in HTML5 within a `section` tag.

Answer (score 3):

According to the spec:

> A header element is intended to usually contain the section's heading (an h1–h6 element or an hgroup element), but this is not required. The header element can also be used to wrap a section's table of contents, a search form, or any relevant logos.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-header-element

So no, you don't have to wrap all your headings in a header tag. It's for a section's heading and/or related elements.

Comment: +1 for linking to the spec. To add to it: Headers are used for things such as titles, author information, date/time-stamps, and any other information that you might find in a header of any other document ever. If you are looking to wrap your `h#` tags, use an `hgroup` element (although it does have some meaning for section division, read the spec to learn more).

Answer (score 1):

Header is the element that covers the heading of any section. This includes the webpage itself, but could also be the heading of a separate section. It helps to think about it by assuming that in some circumstances people may want to reuse only part of your webpage somewhere else.

Say a site that aggregates a series of articles on professions. If you have a page that has 3 separate profession articles, "Fireman", "Policeman", and "Soldier" and each article was wrapped in an `<article>` tag and each had a `<header>` tag that contained the heading for each article, then the aggregating site could easily roll up your articles. The same is true for search engines and web crawlers.

Answer (score 0):

`Header tag` in html5 is basically used to contain the header section of a page. To group H1...H6 tags,  tag has been introduced in html5. So we can use  this tag. And these tags are useful for web crawlers as well. If you use `hgroup` tag in your page, then at the time of crawling search engines treat it as something important and gives more weightage to it.

While studying about impotance of html5 tags for SEO, i found this link. 
[link text](http://www.webconfs.com/html5-seo-article-27.php)